# A stubborn issue with git branch merging

Tags: git, merge, github

There's something I try to do and it always comes down to having to merge different branches manually by resolving conflicts.

The basic kind that always works, is if there is only a single developer working on a branch and then committing the changes,

The problem is - If i have two developers working on different files, how would i merge this two distinct branches into the master branch ? Always when i try i get weird errors from git about fast-forward and such.

I hope my question is clear enough :)

Thanks!

Comment: If the two developers are really working on different files, there should be no problem.

Comment: Just use git merge branchh1 master and then the same with branch2?

Comment: `git merge branch1`, then if successful, `git merge branch2`. Not `git merge branch1 master` (I don't know what that would do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it may help to post the git output to diagnose the problem more accurately. Assuming your master branch doesn't have any problems or uncommitted files i.e. if you run `git status` on your master branch you get this:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If that is the case you can do a couple of things. You can do:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1 branch2
```

This will most likely use Octopus merge to merge everything into master or you can do it separately if you prefer:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1
git merge branch2
```

This way it will try to fast-forward first. If you still get conflicts then I would post the output here. Also as a general rule, it's a good idea to `git merge master` while on your working branch (branch1 or branch2) periodically if you're working on a long project to make sure you take care of the conflicts as they happen, although it may be less important with only two developers.